# AVAssetReader fails to initialise?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation, avassetreader

I am trying to export iCloud assets through AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter but AVAssetReader fails to initialise using that asset. All other videos are working fine. Only iCloud shared album videos are causing trouble. The error AVAssetReader gives me is under:

Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-17507), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x2812d8ae0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-17507 "(null)"}}

Is there any why to fix it or is there any other alternative ?

Comment: I just figured out that it only happens in ios version greater than 12. Probably Apple has made changes in ios 13.

Answer (score 0):

When requesting the asset using `PHImageManager`, setting the `deliveryMode` property of the `PHVideoRequestOptions` instance to `mediumQualityFormat` or `fastFormat` might be the cause of the problem you're experiencing. Try using auto or high quality, because according to the docs, those are the only modes supported when exporting.

```
let videoRequestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
videoRequestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
videoRequestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: videoRequestOptions) { (asset, audioMix, info) in
            // Use the returned asset 
        }
```

Comment: I am already using high quality format and my network access is allow but still facing the same issue with iCloud assets.

Comment: That's interesting. I ran into the same issue and that solved that problem. It wasn't a viable solution for me though because I didn't want to download high quality a version. You can find out more if you look at [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66818642/avassetexportsession-fails-to-export-videos-downloaded-from-icloud)