# AVAssetExportSession fails to export videos downloaded from iCloud

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, photosframework

I'm trying to create a scaled down version of a video selected from the users photo album. The max dimensions of the output will be 720p. Therefore, when retrieving the video, I'm using the `.mediumQualityFormat` as the `deliveryMode`. This causes iOS to retrieve a 720p video from iCloud if the original video or its medium quality version don't exist in the users device.

```
let videoRequestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
videoRequestOptions.deliveryMode = .mediumQualityFormat
videoRequestOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true

PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: videoRequestOptions) { (asset, audioMix, info) in
    // Proceess the asset
}
```

The problem is, when I use `AVAssetExportSession` to create a scaled down version of the asset, if the asset is a medium variant and not the original version, the export process fails immediately with the following error:

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-17507), NSLocalizedDescription=İşlem tamamlanamadı, NSUnderlyingError=0x283bbcf60 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-17507 "(null)"}}
```

I couldn't find anything about the meaning of this error anywhere.

When I set the `deliveryMode` property to `.auto` or `.highQualityFormat`, everything is working properly.

When I checked the asset url's, I noticed that when the video has been retrieved from iCloud, its filename has a ".medium" postfix like in this example:

`file:///var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/Metadata/PhotoData/CPLAssets/group338/191B2348-5E19-4A8E-B15C-A843F9F7B5A3.medium.MP4`

The weird thing is, if I use `FileManager` to copy the video in this url to another directory, create a new `AVAsset` from that file, and use that asset when creating the `AVExportSession` instance, the problem goes away.

I'd really appreciate if someone could provide some insight about what the problem could be.

This is how I use `AVAssetExportSession` to  create a scaled down version of the original video.

```
let originalVideoURL = // The url of the asset retrieved from requestAVAsset

let outputVideoPath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "encodedVideo.mp4"
let outputVideoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: outputVideoPath)

guard
        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality),
        let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first else {
        // Error handling
    return
}

let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
videoComposition.renderSize = scaledSize // How this is calculated is irrelevant
videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(value: 1, timescale: 30)

let layerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: videoTrack)
let transform = videoTrack.preferredTransform

layerInstruction.setTransform(transform, at: .zero)

let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration)
instruction.layerInstructions = [layerInstruction]
videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]

exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition
exportSession.outputURL = outputVideoURL
exportSession.outputFileType = .mp4
exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true

exportSession.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {[weak self] in
    guard let self = self else { return }

    if let url = exportSession.outputURL, exportSession.status == .completed {
        // Works for local videos
    } else {
        // Fails with error code 17507 when loading videos with delivery size "Medium"
    }
})
```